# unable to fix the footer to bottom

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

Sorry for asking this question. I was searching for the past few hours but could not find any help.

fixing footer bottom even when the page doesn't have content and when there is content has to content it should be at the end of content I tried many ways but none worked for me my

```
`<footer class="c-primary ">(tried but getting footer over content static-bottom,fixed-bottom)

  <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">&copy; Beginners Insight  2020
    <a href="http://localhost:8080/Beginners_Insight/index.jsp">BeginnersInsight.com</a><br>
    MADE WITH &hearts; BY Team ITF
  </div>


</footer>`
```

Comment: What are the css-rules of the classes you are using in your example?

Comment: like those css properties are direclty from bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

What you want is set the min height of your page according to the viewport height and keep the footer at the bottom of your page.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    background-color: blue;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

footer {
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Footer bottom test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <header>my header</header>
        <main>

        </main>
        <footer>
            <div> Beginners Insight 2020
                <a href="">BeginnersInsight.com</a>
                MADE WITH &hearts; BY Team ITF
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I forgot a css rule (my bad) "position: relative"